# WidgetKit .supportedFamilies Complications only available for iOS 16.0 or newer

Tags: ios, swiftui, widgetkit, ios16

Within a non-iOS 16 target project when I tried to do

```swift
IntentConfigIntentConfiguration(
    kind: kind,
    intent: SelectIntent.self,
    provider: WidgetProvider()
) { entry in
    WidgetEntry(entry: entry)
}
    .configurationDisplayName("Display Name")
    .description("Description")
    .supportedFamilies([.systemSmall, .systemMedium, .accessoryInline])
```

I got

```
'accessoryInline' is only available in application extensions for iOS 16.0 or newer
```

on `.supportedFamilies([.systemSmall, .systemMedium, .accessoryInline])`

Is there any good ways that I could work around this, so that users with < iOS 16.0 could still use the .systemSmall and .systemMedium widgets, while the users on >= iOS 16.0 could enjoy the lock screen complications?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Found a nice way to use `extensions` which is inspired by [an awesome post](https://davedelong.com/blog/2021/10/09/simplifying-backwards-compatibility-in-swift/) :D

```swift
extension WidgetConfiguration {
    func adaptedSupportedFamilies() -> some WidgetConfiguration {
        if #available(iOS 16, *) {
            return self.supportedFamilies([
                .systemSmall,
                .systemMedium,
                .accessoryInline
            ])
        } else {
            return self.supportedFamilies([
                .systemSmall,
                .systemMedium
            ])
        }
    }
}
```